# How to get a pod external endpoint in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Let's suppose I have pods deployed in a Kubernetes cluster and I have exposed them via a NodePort service. Is there a way to get the pod external endpoint in one command ?

For example:

```
kubectl <cmd>
Response : <IP_OF_NODE_HOSTING_THE_POD>:30120 ( 30120 being the nodeport external port )
```

Comment: kubectl get svc -o wide

Comment: Any of the node IP addresses will work; it does not necessarily need to be a node with at least one of the pods on it.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is a complex one and requires query to list object. I am going to explain with assumptions. Additionally if you need internal address then you can use endpoint object(ep), because the target resolution is done at the endpoint level.

Assumption: 1 Pod, 1 NodePort service(32320->80); both with name nginx

The following command will work with the stated assumption and I hope this will give you an idea for the best approach to follow for your requirement.

Note: This answer is valid based on the assumption stated above. However for more generalized solution I recommend to use `-o jsonpath='{range..` for this type of complex queries. For now the following command will work.

command:

```
kubectl get pods,ep,svc nginx -o jsonpath=' External:http://{..status.hostIP}{":"}{..nodePort}{"\n Internal:http://"}{..subsets..ip}{":"}{..spec.ports..port}{"\n"}'
```

Output:

```
 External:http://192.168.5.21:32320
 Internal:http://10.44.0.21:80
```

Answer (score 0):

If the node port service is known then something like `kubectl get svc <svc_name> -o=jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}:{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}` should work.

Comment: This will return the node port of the service but I want to also have the IP of the node hosting the pod

Comment: The node port service is exposed on all the nodes of the cluster. You can use the IP of any node. Here is a one liner to get the external IP of the first returned node - `kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}'` . External IP is not always available, depending on the specifics of the cluster setup. In such a case, you can use InternalIP, but run the command from a host in the same vnet as the cluster.